# Jquery tokenInput not prePopulating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, jquery-tokeninput

Hi I'm following [this tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields) but prepopulating the field is not working while editing my model..

Note that text_field category_tokens is not pre-populated with categories while editing.

Here are code snippets, the HTML output of the text_field shows the values.

```
  <input id="product_category_tokens" type="text" size="30" name="product[category_tokens]" data-pre="[{"created_at":"2010-09-13T03:33:17Z","description":"","id":x,"name":"Kitchen & Dining ","parent_id":xx,"permalink":"kitchen-dining","updated_at":"2011-01-05T11:17:10Z"}]" style="display: none;">

  application.js
    $(function() {
      $("#product_category_tokens").tokenInput("/categories.json", {
          crossDomain: false,
          prePopulate: $('#product_category_tokens').data('pre'),
          preventDuplicates: true
      });
    });

    <%= f.text_field :category_tokens, "data-pre" => @product.categories.map(&:attributes).to_json %>
```

Comment: Whats your development log look like? any errors from categories.json?

Comment: The categories.json displays correct json format. In fact the plugin works for creating new categories. It's just does not prepopulate current categories while editing the product.

Comment: It should prepopulate from that json url. Are you sure you followed the guide?

Comment: Yes I followed the guide, shouldn't the prepopulation work based on the "data-pre" field <%= f.text_field :category_tokens, "data-pre" => @product.categories.map(&:attributes).to_json %>

Comment: @anshu so you have everything set up and you just changed everything in the tutorial to category instead?

Comment: Happened to me recently. The json objected I was using to prePopulate had a key named `:id` and another one named `:title`, but tokenInput required `:id` and `:name`. Any other key will be ignored, I think, but it's important to have those two.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of: [Jquery tokenInput not prepopulating the text_field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368921/jquery-tokeninput-not-prepopulating-the-text-field)

And the answer is right there at the end:

```
<%= f.text_field :category_tokens, input_html => { "data-pre" => @product.categories.map(&:attributes).to_json } %>
```

I'm not taking credit for this (it's not my answer) just thought I'd point this out in case it helps someone else because I was caught by it too.

I also want to point out that on Shawn's comment, you can get around that by adding this to your js.coffee file:

```
propertyToSearch: "author"
```

Change `author` to whatever your column name is and this will work. `:name` is simply the default but you can override it in this method. More documentation on the jquery tokeninput page: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/